# why i can't use release in objects objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios5

i can't release objects after using it in objective-c i found error

> release is unavailable

example ;

```
strokes *current = [strokesarray] objectAtIndex:0];

[current release]
```

last line is error why ?

Comment: oh, and one more thing... a style suggestion: Objective C class names should be capitalized (e.g. "Strokes") while variables and object names should start with a lower case letter (e.g. "strokesarray" and "current").

Comment: i know it is just an example i wrote it quickly

Comment: You shouldn't release `current` in your example anyway, because even when ARC is off, the object is not yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is this:  since you have [Automated Reference Counting (ARC)](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) turned on in your project, you cannot call "`release`" on objects.

And even if you didn't have ARC turned on, that code would not be correct because A), your brackets in "`[strokesarray] objectAtIndex:0]`" aren't balanced (syntax error) and B) releasing an object stored in an array means your app will crash with an EXEC_BAD_ACCESS error next time you attempt to access that object in the array.

Comment: ok is this a big problem in my code ? i feel that my application become slow after while !!!

Comment: I suspect you have another potentially big problem somewhere else in your code, but not having a "release" isn't it.

Comment: so if ARC is on it will release it automatic if off i should release it myself right ?

Comment: Yep. If this were my project, I'd leave ARC on though.  And run [Instruments (built into Xcode)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/developertools/conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) to see if I can track down where the slowdown is actually occurring.